# Stored data is growing until application stops working

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a small Android app, with no database.

I added google AdMob to my app and when I run the application on my device - the application stored data is growing all the time until it get stuck and I need to clear the data (Android settings > applications > my app > clear data) to make it work again. I deleted the Ads and it stopped.

Is it normal? How can I prevent that?

This is my code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        getOverflowMenu();

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);

            // Create the interstitial.
            interstitial.setAdUnitId("...");
            //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
            final AdView adView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            // Create ad request.
            // Add a test device to show Test Ads
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
             .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
             .addTestDevice("...")
             .build();
            // Load ads into Banner Ads
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);


           // Begin loading your interstitial.
           /* interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
           // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
           interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
              public void onAdLoaded() {
                  // Call displayInterstitial() function
                  displayInterstitial();
              }
              public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){
                 adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
           });
           */
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal. I would start by removing the static reference to the Interstitial.

I suspect that clearing application stored data is not resolving your issue. I suspect that killing and then restarting your app is resolving the issue. You need to distinguish between JVM memory (which I believe is the problem) and cached disk storage.